# jquery click value don't show just white page

Tags: jquery, click, this

hello i have some problem with jquery val()

when i click on div , jquery don't show value just white page, what is incorrect ?

html

```
<div class='item' value='first test'>test</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".item").click(function() {
  var item_id = $(this).val();
  document.write(item_id);
});
```

i know i can use id but i have more than 1 div's

i dont know maybe div don't support value ? 
please help me with this problem or write some similar solution.

Comment: `value` is an invalid attribute for div tags, you can use [`data-*`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attributes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` doesn't support `value`, try `data-` attributes.

```
<div class="baz" data-foo="bar">

$('.baz').data('foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot using `document.write()` after the page has finished rendering.
Instead, you should use jQuery to set the text of an existing element.

And, you cannot use `value`s on non-form-elements.